# watchtower update docker images

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-watchtower

The [watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower/) will update the docker images as and when it pushed to a private or public repo. Is there a way to make it more granular? EX:

**dockeraname**     **imagename**

docker1        ubuntu16.04

docker2        ubuntu16.04

docker3       ubuntu16.04

docker4       ubuntu16.04

with the help watchtower or any other open source tools, how to specify update only docker1 and docker2 to ubuntu latest and keep the docker3 and docker4 with the same version?

Answer (score 0):

You can pin down the tags for each container. Watchtower will only detect changes for the same tag as you used when you launched the container.

In your case, pinning docker3 and docker4 to a version tag, for instance `ubuntu:16.04`, while docker1 and docker2 are kept at `ubuntu:latest`, would produce the desired result.